# How can I fix the unequal space between my references if I combine apacite and \flushleft

Tags: bibtex, horizontal-alignment, bibliographies, line-spacing, apa-style

I have a problem with my references done by `apacite`. My references have to be formatted as flush left entries:

```
   \documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=14pt,DIV=10,twoside, numbers=noenddot, bibliography=totoc, cleardoublepage=empty]{scrbook}
\pagestyle{plain}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{pxfonts}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite} 
\usepackage[osf,sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{ellipsis}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}
\DeclareMicrotypeSet*[tracking]{my}{ font = */*/*/sc/* } 
\SetTracking{ encoding = *, shape = sc }{ 45 }
\usepackage{hyperref}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\setkomafont{caption}{\fontsize{12}{14}\normalfont}
\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\fontsize{12}{14}\bfseries}
\setkomafont{descriptionlabel}{\fontsize{14}{16}\bfseries}
\setcapindent{0em}
\setkomafont{footnote}{\fontsize{12}{14}\normalfont}
\setkomafont{chapter}{\fontsize{18}{20}\normalfont\bfseries}
\setkomafont{chapterentry}{\fontsize{16}{20}\normalfont\bfseries}
\setkomafont{section}{\fontsize{16}{18}\normalfont\bfseries}
\setkomafont{subsection}{\fontsize{14}{16}\normalfont\bfseries}
\setkomafont{subsubsection}{\fontsize{14}{16}\normalfont\bfseries}

\clubpenalty=10000
\widowpenalty=10000
\displaywidowpenalty=10000
\brokenpenalty=10000
\doublehyphendemerits=5000 
\finalhyphendemerits=5000
\tolerance=10000
\urlstyle{same}
\deffootnote{0.75cm}{1em}{\makebox[0.75cm][l]{\thefootnotemark}}

\author{XX} \title{YYY}
\begin{document} 
\maketitle 
\citep{APA1, APA2, Ambady1}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\begin{flushleft}
\bibliography{test}
\end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

I am using apacite with the natbibapa-option (\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}). The test.bib file contains the following three entries:

```
@article{Ambady1,
   author = {Ambady, Nalini and Rosenthal, Robert},
   title = {{Half a minute: Predicting teacher evaluations from thin slices of nonverbal behavior and physical attractiveness}},
   journal = {Journal of Personality and Social Psychology},
   volume = {64},
   number = {3},
   pages = {431-441},
   year = {1993}
}
@book{APA1,
   author = {{American Psychological Association}},
   title = {Publication manual of the {A}merican {P}sychological {A}ssociation},
   publisher = {American Psychological Association},
   address = {Washington},
   year = {2010}
}
@book{APA2,
   author = {{American Psychological Association}},
   title = {{APA} Dictionary of Psychology},
   publisher = {American Psychological Association},
   address = {Washington},
   year = {2007}
}
```

When I am combining `apacite` with `\flushleft` I got unequal line-spacing between some of my references. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Don't use `\flushleft`, to begin with, but the environment `flushleft` around `\bibliography{mybibfile}`. Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Even if I am using the \begin{flushleft} and \end{flushleft} environment, I got the same result and problem.

Comment: My impression is that at the end of each bibitem there is some invisible box that in certain circumstances produces a line break with “nothing visible” in the next line. I guess you're unlucky enough to get this.

Comment: You can try the `FlushLeft` environment that should make the problem less unlikely to happen.

Comment: @egreg 
Thanks a lot, but, oh my god, now I'm answering my own question. I fixed my problem with the following code: `\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\begin{FlushLeft}
\setlength{\biblabelsep}{\baselineskip} 
\bibliography{test.bib}
\end{FlushLeft}`

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use `\flushleft`: this macro exists only to make `\begin{flushleft}` work.

You might be able to solve your problem with

```
\begin{FlushLeft}
\bibliography{mybibfile}
\end{Flushleft}
```

that will make less likely that the final box in the entries produces the bad behavior.

Note that `FlushLeft` is provided by `ragged2e` that you're already loading.